# How to capture trigger words from user input(speech)?

Tags: android-intent, dialogflow-es, webhooks, actions-on-google

I am creating an Action for the Google Home that provides details on remaining insurance coverage. e.g. how much balance is left for Hospital expenses?

How do I capture coverage name from user's voice input? e.g. paramedical, massage therapy, chiropractor, eye exam etc. There is no pre-build entity for this in dialogFlow. So I created an entity called expense. I have added different coverages in this entity. e.g. Hospital as reference value and also as text, for Chiropractor as reference value for texts chiropractor, chiro, chiropractic etc. Idea is I'll capture these expenses and then invoke an API using webhook to get the response. In my training phrases, I have highlighted these words and linked to a parameter which has my expense entity for entity field. When I try my intent either from simulator or device, it's not identifying these expense items and going to default fallback intent. Any idea how to achieve this?

[first screenshot of intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cXsA.png)

[second screenshot of intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1qlZ.png)

[Screenshot of entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmTzX.png)

Comment: Please only ask one question per StackOverflow post, particularly when there is a fairly thin connection between the two questions. Go ahead and update the question so you only ask one here, and the other in a new post. It also really helps us if you include  what you've already tried that isn't working - in these cases, showing screen shots of the Intents and Entities in question would help us help you with the problems. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/hey-google-i-need-help-with-my-action-8cf09714a20d

Comment: Can you update your question to show screen shots of the Intents and Entities that don't seem to be working?

Comment: added screenshots. any suggestions?

Comment: Any one with any suggestions? I am not able to make this work.

Comment: I haven't been able to duplicate your problem using the Intent and Entity you described. You've tagged this with actions-on-google, can you update the question with the contents of the "request", "response", and "debug" tabs from the simulator, and also with a screen shot of the simulator when it shows the error?